# Pulling the latest record when there are multiple records with different dates in Oracle HCM

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-fusion-apps

I am written a query which pulls work schedule data on person level in Oracle Fusion HCM. What is the filter or the join condition which I need to add to pull the latest date column.
I have used the tables

**PER_SCHEDULE_ASSIGNMENTS PSA
, ZMM_SR_SCHEDULES_TL ZSST
, PER_ALL_ASSIGNMENTS_M PAAM
, PER_ALL_PEOPLE_F PAPF**

The query returns 4 rows with different dates. How to return only 1 row which has the latest date column in it?

Answer (score 0):

Use *SYSDATE BETWEEN EFFECTIVE_START_DATE AND EFFECTIVE_END_DATE* in all the tables where the date start date is there.

This will get you the current row as of today from those tables. You won't have any duplicates anymore.